# Google Contacts API - Updating Birthdays and Anniversaries

Tags: php, xml, api, google-api, google-contacts-api

I am trying to update my google contacts using the API.
I know through php we can send an UPDATE to the contact by posting a XML file.

I am not 100% sure what the xml is supposed to look like to house the birthday element.
This what I currently have.

```
<atom:entry xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:gd="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005">
  <gd:name>
    <gd:givenname>John</gd:givenname>
    <gd:familyname>Doe</gd:familyname>
  </gd:name>
  <gd:birthday when="2011-09-09"></gd:birthday>
</atom:entry>
```

And I have NO Clue as to how to format the **Anniversary** (event). I can't seem to find any documentation on this online. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I pull it from Google Contacts it looks like this:

```
<gContact:event rel="anniversary">
  <gd:when startTime="1981-10-15"/>
</gContact:event>
```

Comment: Sweet thanks, i will give that a go and let you know... any thoughts for Birthdays???

Comment: <gContact:birthday when="1950-01-15"/>

Comment: That is awesome, took me awhile to get it to work, for some reason I was being dense and forgot to add the name-space... xmlns:gContact='http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008      cheers thanks